# Number of commits in a git repository

Tags: svn, git

A 5 month project of mine is nearing its end and as a fan of pointless statistics,
I'd like to know how many commits have been made since the repository's inception.

How do I find that out?

Notes:

1. I know there is no *one* repository, I'm just interested in the local version.
2. This is trivial in subversion, as the revision identifier 
   seems to be the commit number.

Comment: Actually, SVN revisions are only guaranteed to be monotonic, not consecutive. It's perfectly fine for a repository to contain six revisions numbered 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To get the number of commits on the current branch:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

For a more complete count, use:

```
git rev-list --all | wc -l
```

See the docmentation for git rev-list for details on specifying objects to count.

It is tempting to try something like:

```
find .git/objects -type f | wc -l
```

but this will not count packed objects.  It's best to stick with git rev-list.

Comment: Thanks, git gurus. I know this wasn't the first wc -l solution, but the fact that this looks at the current branch is good to know.

Comment: And of course you can count number of commits since some revision with e.g. "git rev-list v0.9.. | wc -l".  And there is also git-shortlog (see its documentation).

Comment: Also note that you can skip merge commits with `git log --no-merges` since merge commits can pad your stats.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ git shortlog -s     # or git shortlog -s -n
     2  Adam Jacob
     2  Matt Ray
    19  Mike Adolphs
   151  John Jackson
    36  jtimberman
     2  mattray
     4  bkilroy
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but is a good metric to know about. +1.

Answer (score 6):

There may be a more elegant way to do it, but I would just run:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

Others have already posted the easiest answers but here are a couple of options that might also be of interest.

[Easy Git](http://www.gnome.org/~newren/eg/) is a simple, light-weight wrapper (single file perl script) for Git.  One nice feature that it adds to Git is an "info" command (run: `eg info`) that gives some nice info about your repository, including the number of commits, files, directories, contributors and largest file.

[GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/) is another tool that gives you all kinds of nice plots of statistics about your repository.  Checkout their [examples](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/), e.g., [an analysis of the git project](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/git/).

Answer (score 2):

Just run 'gitk'. It will also show the number of commits on the screen.