# Count how many new commits were made

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have a branch `my_branch` that was branched off of master. I would like to see how many commits have been created on `my_branch` since the split from master. I know I can do `git log master..benzinga` to see all the commits - but I want to get a count rather than a list of commits. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could compare branch counts.

```
git rev-list --count BRANCHNAME
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913892/number-of-commits-on-branch-in-git