# git list remote branches, order by number of commits

Tags: git

There is `git branch -r` to list all remote branches.

I wonder if there is away to list all remote branches, but order them by number of commits (eg., the branch with most commits is listed first).

Comment: I don't know how to sort `git branch` as you'd like, but as a step in the right direction [this is how you can determine how many commits are on each branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913892/number-of-commits-on-branch-in-git)

Comment: There is nothing built in. You could build it easily enough, using `git for-each-ref`, `git rev-list --count`, and the `sort` program. The result would not be very useful though as the count of commits on a branch is hardly ever worthwhile: a new branch, just created right now from `master`, has every commit that `master` has. (You probably want to redefine "how many commits" as something like "how many *unique* commits", perhaps.)

Comment: @torek "the count of commits on a branch is hardly ever worthwhile" I guess one usage is that it can filter out unused/obsolete branches (that have very commits) and tidy up the repo. That's a reason I asked. I'll try out your suggestions

Comment: @artm: See VonC's answer for one way to count commits across a symmetric difference between two branches. The more common expression is `git rev-list --count X..Y` (two dots rather than three): `X..Y` means `Y ^X` which means "the set of all commits on `Y` minus the set of all commits on `X`" (i.e., set subtraction), and `--count` then counts the number of elements in that set. Here `Y` is the branch you want to count, but you must also name some other branch `X`, otherwise in a typical repository with tens of thousands of commits, you will find tens of thousands of commits on every branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess one usage is that it can filter out unused/obsolete branches (that have very commits) and tidy up the repo

That is what you see in the "branches" tab section of a GitHub project:

Example for [git/git/branches](https://github.com/git/git/branches):

[image: git/git/branches]

What you want is *not* the number of commits, but, for a given branch acting as reference, [the number of commit ahead and behind that branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940027/6309).

```
git rev-list --left-right --count master...test-branch
```

That way you can see the one behind that could be safely removed.
Note that you can already [list those merged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227026/6309) with:

```
git branch --merged master
```

[With Git 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720302/6309), you can also list local branches compared to their remote tracking branches (not your case, but can be useful):

```
git fetch
git for-each-ref --format="%(push:track)" refs/heads
```

Comment: Interesting, I never knew `--count` could be combined with `--left-right` to count the left and right sides of the symmetric difference!

Comment: @torek I still feel, after seeing the kind of shorthand like `%(push:track)`, there should be a shorthand for that kind of behind/ahead display between two branches.

Comment: Well, there is (sort of), but only for `@{u}`, and it's `git status` :-) The @{upstream} syntax is not very pretty, but the only alternative I know of is Mercurial's generalized expression parser, which is heavy-weight. It has great power, but with shell vagaries requiring quoting, it's pretty klunky syntactically too.

Comment: Thanks @VonC . The ahead/behind info you provided is great. I also wanted to know which branches have only one or two commits - that way I can indentify those branches that had been created but not used and delete them. Some old branches can be a lot behind master but their commits may still be useful to keep.

Comment: @artm those same command will do that: a branch has one or two commits compared to another branch.